# Updating Salesforce object with WSO2 Rest API Connector

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm try to update Account object in Salesforce with the use of WSO2 salesforce rest API connector.as per the documentation is as follow

```
<salesforcerest.update>
    <sObjectName>{$ctx:sObjectName}</sObjectName>
    <fieldAndValue>{$ctx:fieldAndValue}</fieldAndValue>
    <Id>{$ctx:Id}</Id>
</salesforcerest.update>
```

does anyone have an idea what should be the format **fieldAndValue**.
I have tried giving the attribute tag and the value.But it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't used the Rest API so far (only soap), but it looks to me like you have to pass attribut:value to salesforce.

[Salesforce doku](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_update_fields.htm)

According to the wso2 docu I would try it like to pass a json like this.

[wso2 docu](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+Records#WorkingwithRecords-update)

"fieldAndValue": {
    "name": "wso2",
    "description":"This Account belongs to WSO2"
  }

or the values inside the like this.

{
    "name": "wso2",
    "description":"This Account belongs to WSO2"
  }

Hope that helps.